# Ionic 2 custom google map native infowindow

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, google-maps-markers, ionic-native

I'm working with ionic 2 app and i'm trying to add a custom info window from an ionic template with native google map plugin but I'm not able to set the content. Seems like ionic 2 does not support the infowindow object. Can I get some info or documentation about this?

In short words, I'm trying to do something like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows?hl=en-419 (open an info window section, html contentString)
in ionic 2 with native google map plugin.

Edit:
Still trying to find a solution for this where I can use a custom template on infowindow content at @ionic-native/google-maps package, I already have it done with canvas but nothing about HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Marker#base64-encoded-icon

That's a workaround, because seems that it's not supported on version 1.x, but from the v2-beta supports HTML infoWindow,
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1022.

Comment: 1st of all, thank you for your answer.I don't know if I'm missing something but I'm trying to use this : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/ maybe you can actually create a custom html marker but i still can't find how.